# How can I Inject jQuery tooltip code into React via NPM or Hook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins

jQuery code is injected in the root file of React project and now it needs to use via the NPM package. can anyone help me or give any suggestions?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-bs-toggle=tooltip]', trigger : 'hover', html:true });
  });

  function hideTooltip() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `import $ from 'jquery';` and `useEffect`/`componentDidmount`

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import TodoList from './refs/TodoList';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-bs-toggle=tooltip]', trigger : 'hover', html: true });
    }, []) 

    return (
        <div>
            <TodoList />
        </div>)
};

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container!);
root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't. It is not recommended to use jQuery inside of a react application.

As React states in its documentation :

"Just because it’s possible, doesn’t mean that it’s the best approach for React apps. We encourage you to use React components when you can. React components are easier to reuse in React applications, and often provide more control over their behavior and appearance."

You can achieve this by simply using CSS (:hover & adjacent sibling selector)

You can also use a library which will do the trick for you, no need to reinvent the wheel

Here is a code sample to illustrate my words :

```css
.tooltip-container {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-content {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.tooltip-hoverable:hover + .tooltip-content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-container">
  <p class="tooltip-hoverable">
    Hover me
  </p>
  <span class="tooltip-content">I'm the tooltip</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I do agree with you @sebastiencn regarding the jQuery in React framework, However, The application is already built and the code was written earlier hence its not a good time to revamp entire stuff hence looking for quick fix.